# Results changed after sorting a table

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have a following scenario:

I created a batch job using SQL API.

`final TableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.create(EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().inBatchMode().build());`

I load the data from csv files, convert/aggregate it using SQL API.

At some stage I have a table:

```
CREATE VIEW ohlc_current_day as
SELECT
    CAST(transact_time as DATE) as `day`,
    instrument_id,
    first_value(price) as `open`,
    min(price) AS `low`,
    max(price) AS `high`,
    last_value(price) as `close`,
    count(*) AS `count`,
    sum(quantity) AS volume,
    sum(quantity * price) AS turnover
FROM trades //table loaded from csv
group by CAST(transact_time as DATE), instrument_id
```

Now when check the results:

```
select * from ohlc_current_day where instrument_id=14
+------------+---------------+---------+---------+--------+---------+-------+-----------+---------------+
|        day | instrument_id |    open |     low |   high |   close | count |    volume |      turnover |
+------------+---------------+---------+---------+--------+---------+-------+-----------+---------------+
| 2021-04-11 |            14 |  1723.0 |  1709.0 | 1743.0 |  1728.0 |   679 |  487470.0 |   8.4114803E8 |
+------------+---------------+---------+---------+--------+---------+-------+-----------+---------------+
```

The results are repeatable and correct (checked with reference).

Then, for futrher processing, I need ohlc values from the previous day which are already stored in a database:

```
CREATE TABLE ohlc_database (
  `day` TIMESTAMP,
  instrument_id INT,
  `open` float,
  `low` FLOAT,
  `high` FLOAT,
  `close` FLOAT,
  `count` BIGINT,
  volume FLOAT,
  turnover FLOAT
) WITH (
 'connector' = 'jdbc',
 'url' = 'url',
 'table-name' = 'ohlc',
 'username' = 'user',
 'password' = 'password'
)
```

Let's now merge ohlc_current_day with ohlc_database:

```
CREATE VIEW ohlc_raw as
SELECT * from ohlc_current_day
UNION ALL
select
    CAST(`day` as DATE) as `day`,
    instrument_id,
    `open`,
    `low`,
    `high`,
    `close`,
    `count`,
    volume,
    turnover
FROM ohlc_database
WHERE `day` = '2021-04-10' //hardcoded previous day date
```

And check the results:

```
select * from ohlc_raw where instrument_id=14
+------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+---------+-------+-----------+---------------+
|        day | instrument_id |   open |    low |   high |   close | count |    volume |      turnover |
+------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+---------+-------+-----------+---------------+
| 2021-04-10 |            14 | 1696.0 | 1654.0 | 1703.0 |  1691.0 |   936 | 1040888.0 |  1.74619264E9 |
| 2021-04-11 |            14 | 1723.0 | 1709.0 | 1743.0 |  1728.0 |   679 |  487470.0 |   8.4114829E8 |
+------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+---------+-------+-----------+---------------+
```

results are ok, values the same as in previous select query.

Now let's order by day:

```
CREATE VIEW ohlc as
SELECT * from ohlc_raw ORDER BY `day`
```

Check the results:

```
select * from ohlc where instrument_id=14
+------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|        day | instrument_id |            open |             low |        high |          close |                count |                         volume |                       turnover |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 2021-04-10 |            14 |          1696.0 |          1654.0 |      1703.0 |         1691.0 |                  936 |                      1040888.0 |                   1.74619264E9 |
| 2021-04-11 |            14 |          1729.0 |          1709.0 |      1743.0 |         1732.0 |                  679 |                       487470.0 |                    8.4114854E8 |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

`open` and `close` are wrong compared to previous values. They are calculated using `first_value()` and `last_value()` functions which depend on the order of elements. So my guess is that `order by` in last query has changed the order and this is why there are different results.

Is my understanding correct? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I thought that `first_value()` or `last_value()` themself is a sort operation. When you `order by` in last query, the sort according to `last_value()` is out of order. May be you can output the result into database after `union all`, and then do `order by` date after extract data from database if possible.